# Flash Plugin For Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flash

I tried to install "flashplugin-installer" in Ubuntu but it didn't work for me.

The reason that I can't use the Adobe version is because this happens:

```
client socket: Invalid argument
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: failed to initialize plugin-side RPC client connection
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-wrapper.c:3156):invoke_NP_Initialize: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(g_rpc_connection))
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99.0".
server socket: Invalid argument
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** ERROR: failed to initialize plugin-side RPC server connection
```

Comment: The easiest thing for you to do is install Google Chrome which has Flash built-in.

Comment: Asking for product recommendations (i.e. "what do you recommend for a Flash plugin") is off topic here. The problem below it would keep it on topic

Answer (score 2):

i'd recommend 'flashplugin-nonfree' or 'ubuntu-restricted-extras'. The other flash plugins might be ideologically purer (the main advantage) but for most part, the adobe flash plugin has the best functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flash plugin works very good. Maybe you should explain what did you do, and what do you mean by "didn't work" (at all or just some flash objects), so somebody can help you to solve this.

Comment: See my new edit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , this scripts automates the installation of flash plugin for firefox and removes the exiting version from the machines and install a clear version of flash and adds a plugin to firefox [flash.sh](http://ukanth.in/files/flash.sh)

Comment: (-1). Please explain briefly what the script does. Asking people to execute a script, with no explanation as to what it does, sets a dangerous precedent.